# GNOME freezes completely with Xorg using 100% cpu

Tags: 18.04, gnome, xorg

I have a Dell XPS 13 9380 running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with GNOME. Occasionally (about once a day), my system will lock up completely. I usually notice this issue when switching from my terminal to another window (Firefox or Slack).

I am still able to ssh to the system from another machine, and I see that Xorg is using 100% CPU. I am unable to kill the Xorg process, and shutting down the machine (with `sudo shutdown 0`) kicks me out of my ssh session, but does not actually shutdown the machine. The only way I can shut down the machine and restore sanity is to hold the power button until it forces a shutdown.

Here are some logs starting from just before the system froze. The time frozen on my clock was 10:25:42, so I have logs from slightly before that time. https://pastebin.com/fSHg4rQD

Related questions I've seen have mentioned drivers as a potential issue, so I've reproduced the output of `lspci | grep VGA` and `glxinfo | grep string` below. Given that I have only Intel graphics on this machine, the drivers reported by these utilities don't seem to be the problem.

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0 (rev 02)
```

```
$ glxinfo | grep string
server glx vendor string: SGI
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
client glx version string: 1.4
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) UHD Graphics (Whiskey Lake 3x8 GT2)-
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 19.0.8
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

```
$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15G        5.2G        3.7G        2.7G        6.4G        7.1G
Swap:           31G        5.8M         31G
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C memory
  *-firmware
       description: BIOS
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.9.1
       date: 12/03/2019
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 15MiB
       capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppynec int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 2d
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 16GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: H9CCNNNCLGALAR-NVD
          vendor: SK Hynix
          physical id: 0
          slot: System Board Memory
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: Row of chips LPDDR3 Synchronous 2133 MHz (0.5 ns)
          product: H9CCNNNCLGALAR-NVD
          vendor: SK Hynix
          physical id: 1
          slot: System Board Memory
          size: 8GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2133MHz (0.5ns)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 36
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 256KiB
       capacity: 256KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 37
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1MiB
       capacity: 1MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 38
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 8MiB
       capacity: 8MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:dc51c000-dc51dfff memory:dc522000-dc522fff
```

```
$ sudo sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

```
$ grep -i swap /etc/fstab
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Edit:
I was able to reproduce the issue on BIOS version 1.9.1

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory`.

Comment: Also show me `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Do you want to see `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory` while the system is frozen or in regular operation?

Comment: Please show me all 3 commands in regular operation. You won't be able to do it when the machine is frozen. Thanks!

Comment: Edited with the outputs. FWIW I am able to connect to the machine and run some commands while the machine is frozen. That's how I was able to see Xorg taking 100% of CPU. I also don't have a `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` directory or file.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I see that you've done the BIOS update as per my original answer. Good! I notice that your swap is excessive. Show me `sudo sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 1):

Update your BIOS from 1.8.0 to 1.9.1 by going to [here.](https://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=12kvy&oscode=wt64a&productcode=xps-13-9380-laptop)

## BIOS 1.9.1

```
Fixes & Enhancements
Fixes:
- Firmware updates to address security advisory INTEL-SA-00241 (CVE-2019-0169, CVE-2019-11105, CVE-2019-11104, CVE-2019-11103, CVE-2019-11090, CVE-2019-0165, CVE-2019-0168, CVE-2019-11087, CVE-2019-11101, CVE-2019-11106, CVE-2019-11108, CVE-2019-11147, CVE-2019-11088, CVE-2019-0131, CVE-2019-0166, CVE-2019-11100, CVE-2019-11107, CVE-2019-11086, CVE-2019-11132, and CVE-2019-11131).
- Firmware updates to address Intel security advisories INTEL-SA-00220 (CVE-2019-0124), INTEL-SA-00260 (CVE-2019-0154), and INTEL-SA-00254 (CVE-2019-0185).
- Firmware updates to address Intel security advisories INTEL-SA-00219 (CVE-2019-0117), INTEL-SA-00220 (CVE-2019-0123), and INTEL-SA-00270 (CVE-2019-11135).
- Fixed a BIOS Setup configuration issue that occurs after clearing the CMOS.
- Fixed an issue with preboot TPM detection and error logging.
- Fixed the issue where the keyboard and touchpad lags when the system is connected to a Dell U2419HC monitor using the USB Type-C port.
- Removed the IpSec driver and application.

Enhancements:
- Added an enhancement to extend the BIOS password configuration measurements into the TPM.
- Updated the system Power Delivery firmware.
- Update the Dell Firmware Update Utility.
```

## Installation instructions

```
Updating the BIOS from Windows

Note 1: Before updating the BIOS, ensure that you suspend BitLocker encryption on a BitLocker-enabled system. If it is not enabled on your system, you can ignore this step. For information about how to disable BitLocker, see How to Enable or Disable BitLocker with TPM in Windows at support.dell.com.
Note 2: Do not turn off the power or interrupt the BIOS update process during the update.

Download and Installation
1. Click Download File, to download the file.
2. Click Save to save the file to your hard drive.
3. Browse to the location where you downloaded the file and double-click the new file.
The system restarts automatically and updates the BIOS at the system startup screen. After the BIOS update is complete, system restarts again.

Updating the BIOS from BIOS Boot Menu (independent of operating system)
Note 1: Before updating the BIOS, ensure that you suspend BitLocker encryption on a BitLocker-enabled system. If it is not enabled on your system, you can ignore this step. For information about how to disable BitLocker, see How to Enable or Disable BitLocker with TPM in Windows at support.dell.com.
Note 2: Do not turn off the power or interrupt the BIOS update process during the update.

Installation
1. Copy the downloaded file to a USB drive. The USB drive does not need to be bootable device.
2. Insert the USB drive into any USB port.
3. Power on the system.
4. At the DELL logo screen, press F12 to access the one-time boot menu.
5. Select BIOS Update in the section.
6. Click Flash from file to browse the USB drive to locate the downloaded file.
7. Select the file and click Submit.
8. Verify the existing system BIOS information and the BIOS update information.
9. Click Update BIOS.
10. Review the Warning message and click Confirm Update BIOS! to proceed with the update.
The system restarts and displays a progress bar at the Dell logo screen. The system restarts again when the update is complete.
```

Comment: I reproduced the issue even on this BIOS version.

Comment: @NickWhite Obtain the `Service Tag #` from the bottom of your computer, and give Dell Support a call. I think this problem requires their support. Report back.